# When Should I synchronize the methods of my class?

Tags: java

I was thinking about creating a class (like String, StringBuffer etc).  This can be used in single-threaded as well as in multi-threaded environments.  I do not know which kind of environment a developer might be using it.  Anticipating the worst-case, I can synchronize.

But,
1. Synchronization takes a performance hit.
2. Without synchronization, it is not thread-safe.

So, I have two options.

1. Leave the class unsynchronized - but the developer using this class needs to synchronize it whenever appropriate.
2. Have all synchronized methods - and take a performance hit.

I have seen that many (if not all.  for eg, ArrayList over Vector) classes in Java have evolved to take the first approach.  What are some of the things I need to consider before deciding on these two options for my class?

Or to put it in a different way, should I use "public synchronized void bar()" over "public void bar()" only when I know **for sure** that bar can be used in a multi-threaded environment and should not be run at the same time?

**EDIT**  So, clearly I have mis-used the word "utility class" in the heading.  Thanks, Jon Skeet, for pointing it out.  I have removed the world "utility" from the heading.

To give an example, I was thinking about a class like, say, Counter.  Counter is just as an example.  There are other ways to implement Counter.  But this question is about synchronization.  A Counter object keeps track of how many times *something* has been done.  But it can possibly be used in single-threaded or multi-threaded environments.  So, how should I handle the problem of synchronization in Counter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What *I* think of as a utility class - typically a grab-bag of vaguely-related public static methods - rarely requires any synchronization. Unless the class maintains some mutable state, you're usually absolutely fine.

Of course, if you take parameters which are *themselves* shared between threads and contain mutable state, you may need synchronization - but that should be for the caller to decide, usually.

If you mean something else by "utility class" it would be good to know what you mean. If it's a class with no mutable state (but perhaps *immutable* state, set at construction) then it's typically fine to share between threads.

If it has mutable state but isn't *explicitly* about threading, I would typically not put any synchronization within that class, but document that it's *not* thread-safe. Typically the callers would need to synchronize multiple operations using multiple objects anyway, so "method at a time" synchronization doesn't typically help.

If it's a class which is all about threading (e.g. something to manage producer/consumer queues) then I would try to make it thread-safe, but document what you mean by that. I'd encourage you *not* to make the methods themselves synchronize, but instead synchronize on a private final field which is *only* used for synchronization; that way your class will contain the *only* code which could possibly synchronize on that object, making it easier to reason about your locking.

You should almost certainly *not* make these decisions on the basis of performance. Correctness and easy of is *far* more important than performance in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your last question: you don't synchronize a method if it can be called from multiple threads. You synchronize a method if it uses some state that can be accessed from multiple threads.

So, even if your `bar()` method is called from only one thread, if it accesses an instance variable which is read and modified, through other methods, by multiple threads, then the `bar()` method must be synchronized (or at least, the block of code which accesses the shared variable). Synchronization is all about shared state.

EDIT:

Regarding your main problem: you could simply use the same strategy as the collection framework: make your Counter an interface, and provide a default, non-thread-safe implementation. Also provide a utility class (`Counters`) containing a method which returns a synchronized Counter proxy: `Counters.synchronizedCounter(Counter counter);`.

This way, you have the best of both worlds. Note that an important point of this design is that the synchronized counter is synchronized on itself. This makes it possible for the callers to add external synchronization in case two method calls on the counter must be done in an atomic way:

```
Counter synchronizedCounter = Counters.synchronizedCounter(c);
// call a and b atomically:
synchronized (synchronizedCounter) {
    synchronizedCounter.a();
    synchronizedCounter.b();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While performance of synchronization has been improved, so are other parts of VM. Therefore synchronization is still a noticeable overhead.

Particularly, synchronization actions prevent lots of optimization tricks. Even if VM can do escape analysis, VM still must withheld reordering and add memory barrier, to conform to Java Memory Model.

Answer (score 0):

These days, the "performance hit" from synchronization is remarkably small. You should only be concerned about it if you have proof that synchronization is causing a performance problem.

You might need synchronization if your class has state via static fields that are references by multiple methods. In this case, it would be preferable to have instance fields and use the singleton pattern, which will convey to other programmers more clearly what the intention of the class is.

Answer (score 0):

The performance penalty for single-thread access to synchronized methods is pretty much negligible on modern JVMs.

But why not create a benchmark and see for yourself?